# I have a long string which contains dates in multiple formats (dd-mm-yyyy, mm-dd-yyyy etc.) . How do I convert them all into the same format?

Tags: python, regex, string, datetime, parsing

I am working on Python. I have many long texts of data. Each text can be treated as a string. Within each string, I need to separate the string into elements of a list where ever a date is present.

```
eg. long string1 (date format: mm.dd.yyyy): 

05.12.2016 15:58:31 jsfkgskdlfsgfdslkcbj 05.13.2016 15:58:31  sdfasjdcakscsdv
01.14.2016fsdkjgfdhkvjxdbvxd

eg. long string2 (date format: dd/mm/yyyy): 

05/12/2016 15:58:31 jsfkgskdlfsgfdslkcbj 05.1.2016 15:58:31  sdfasjdcakscsdv
21/11/2016fsdkjgfdhkvjxdbvxd
```

> **Step1:** I need to write a generalized code such that I can pass both strings in the same code.
>
> **Step2:** Objective of the code is to convert string into list with elements
>   separated by date.

eg. long string 1 to list 1
[05.12.2016 15:58:31 jsfkgskdlfsgfdslkcbj, 05.13.2016 15:58:31  sdfasjdcakscsdv, 01.14.2016fsdkjgfdhkvjxdbvxd]

> **Step 3:** and then take the element with the earliest date
>
> **output from above example:** 01.14.2016fsdkjgfdhkvjxdbvxd

I got help for doing Step 2 and 3 and I can do it when all strings have the same date format. But my challenge is first reading a string and figuring out which date format it is using and then parsing and sorting it on the basis of date

I have code if one date format is given.

```
text = '05/12/2016 15:58:31 jsfkgskdlfsgfdslkcbj 05.1.2016 15:58:31  sdfasjdcakscsdv 21/11/2016fsdkjgfdhkvjxdbvxd'

list1 = list()
for d, t in zip(*[iter(re.split(r'(\d+[\/.]\d+[\/.]\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)', text)[1:])]*2):
    list1.append(d + t)

from datetime import datetime
list_sorted=sorted(list1,key=lambda s: datetime.strptime(s[0:19], "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") if '.' in s[0:19] else datetime.strptime(s[0:19], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))

complaint = list_sorted[0]
print(complaint)
```

The above code works well for a single string for a single date format. How do I generalize it to first detect the date format in the string and then parse it accordingly

Comment: You can use `dateutil.parser` for the same @SakshiJajodia check if my answer below makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dateutil.parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) present in the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) module which can parse the date-time string for you irrespective of the format

```
In [17]: from dateutil import parser                                                                                                                                                   

In [18]: parser.parse('05/12/2016 15:58:31', fuzzy=True)                                                                                                                                           
Out[18]: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 12, 15, 58, 31)

In [19]: parser.parse('05.1.2016 15:58:31', fuzzy=True)                                                                                                                                            
Out[19]: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 15, 58, 31)

In [20]: parser.parse('21/11/2016', fuzzy=True)                                                                                                                                                    
Out[20]: datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 21, 0, 0)
```

Or another example which collects the datetime objects and sort the original list according to it

```
from dateutil import parser

#List of textdate srings
textdate = ['5.13.2001 21:23:54 fgdsgd', '05.12.2001 09:43:32 arfehfks']

#Collect datetime objects
dates = []
for item in textdate:
    dates.append(parser.parse(item, fuzzy=True))

#Sort datetime objects and obtained original list on sorting
res = [textdate[i[0]] for i in sorted(enumerate(dates), key=lambda x:x[1])]
print(res)
```

The output will be

```
['05.12.2001 09:43:32 arfehfks', '5.13.2001 21:23:54 fgdsgd']
```